# VisualForce page displaying in Lightning with no style

Tags: visualforce, slds

I was trying to use a lightning spinner on a visualforce page, I got it working by changing a few things: I added `<apex:slds />`, changed the api number, and set `applyBodyTag`. I think that's all I did. Now I don't want to use the lightning spinner and I am trying to revert my changes but the vf page is rendering as plain text, I undid the three changes above but it still shows as plain. I don't remember what API number we were using before, could that cause the problem? The page is too long to post here any suggestions of where to look will be welcome.

[image]

Also I realize it's only the details section: 
[image]

Comment: Use attribute `lightningStylesheets=true` in `<apex:page>` tag.

Comment: @Pragati Jain It's there

Comment: what's ur api version?

Comment: I think I set it to 41.0 when working on the spinner, I just set it back to 38, then 37. That didn't work, I believe we were using 37 before.

Comment: Have you removed `applyBodyTag=false`?

Comment: Yea, I also set it to true then deleted it. I'm pretty sure it's something else. Thank You!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84007/discussion-between-pragati-jain-and-madmax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a current problem with Winter 19 that started happening yesterday.  The lightningStylesheet is not being retrieved from the server.  if you inspect the page and look at the console log you will see that there is a 500 error.